# Swift checking nil using if-let from a class level

Tags: swift, null

I've been using nested if let(s) to check nils. For example, a class that contains name and age

```
class Person {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
}

if let p = Person() as? Person {
    if let name = p.name {

    }
    if let age = p.age {

    }
}
```

When I'm unsure if a variable is empty/null, is it necessary to use if let on everything and everytime? just trying to make sure if im doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

You need `if-let` only when you need to check for `nil` and use the *unwrapped* value. Otherwise you can simply check for `nil` using `!=` or `==` operator.

Also there is no need to explicitly typecast `p` to `Person` using `as? Person`, since the type can be inferred already.

```
let p = Person()
if p.name != nil {

}
if p.age != nil {

}
```

Comment: OK! Ok.....im getting excited, so i just need to check the first (person class in this example) then for the rest i can just use if something != nil?

Comment: Didn't get you. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry,  was too excited, was just confirming

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check anything

```
p = Person()
```

creating a new Person object with no initial values means that all properties are nil so the following checks are unnecessary, we already know they are nil

```
if let name = p.name {

if let age = p.age {
```

I would suggest you add a constructor with parameters so that you can set the properties directly

Either with mandatory values so you don't have to check for nil afterwards

```
 init(name: String, age: Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
 }
```

or with optional values

```
 init(name: String?, age: Int?) {
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
 }
```

but then you need to check

```
var name: String?
var age: Int?
//...other code

let p = Person(name: name, age: age)
if let personName = p.name {

}
if let personAge = p.age {

}
```